# make columns take fullwidth below 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap 3.3.7.

I cannot understand why my pictures is not taking fullwidth between the viewport range of: `> 630px` and `< 768px`. The pictures have a width of `400px` which is fitting good `> 768px`.

I can make the pictures fit on `< 768px` if I make the width 800 px. But then the picture are getting way to big on `>768px`.

Is it possible to keep the width as it is now, but make the pictures go fullwidth `<768px`?

A demo version can be [seen here](http://vouzalis.dk/test.html)

```css
  /* Card and Button */

    body {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    div { 
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .index-content a:hover {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .index-content {
      /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
      /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
    }

    .index-content .row {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .index-content a {
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .index-content .card:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: black;
    }

    .index-content .card img {
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      height: 350px;
    }

    .index-content .card h4 {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .index-content .card p {
      margin: 20px;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button {
      width: 100px;
      -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
      /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
      min-height: 20px;
      background-color: #002E5B;
      color: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: lighter;
      margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .index-content .blue-button:hover {
      background-color: #dadada;
      color: #002E5B;
    }

    /* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .card {
            position: relative;
        }
        .card-content {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
        .card-content h4,
        .card-content p {
            color: white;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 5px;
        }
        .card-content a {
            float: right;
        }
        .index-content .card h4,
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .index-content .card p {
            padding: 0 20px 15px;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    .margin_bottom{
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"]{ 
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px; 
    }
    .row { 
        margin-left: -5px; 
        margin-right: -5px; 
    }
    
    .card-img-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x245" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using min-width: 768px media query, you can simply add this css rule for it to work below 768px:

```
.img-responsive {width:100%;}
```

If you are unwilling to override bootstrap's default classes, you can come up with your own class and apply it to each image.

Comment: That seems to solve the problem. I can see the height is very big on come of the columns. Is it possible to minimize the height on some specific columns on `<768px`?

Comment: @MK-DK what do you mean by "minimize the height"?

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```css
/* Card and Button */

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index-content {
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
}

.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-content a {
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 350px;
}

.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}


/* GRID ELEMENTS MEDIA QUERIES */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.margin_bottom {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.row [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.card-img-bottom {
  color: #fff;
  height: 20rem;
  background: url(images/img1.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x245" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tried your code on grid 3: http://vouzalis.dk/stack.html. The suggested code is going full width, and not holding the margin:-(

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom"> <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img> </div> <div class="col-sm-4"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 margin_bottom"> <img src="http://placehold.it/400x245" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img> </div> <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 margin_bottom"> <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-sm-4 margin_bottom"> <img src="http://placehold.it/400x510" alt="5" class="img-responsive"></img> </div> </div> </div>
```

Replace your html with this one, You just have to add col-md-12 to your code.
Or you can achieve this using media queries. Here you go:

```
@media (max-width:767px){.col-sm-12 img{width:100%;}}
```